# New user creation in test case

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a new user in django rest framework test case in order to be able to create a post action with the following code:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

user = User.objects.create_user('username', 'Pas$w0rd')
user = authenticate(username='username', password='Pas$w0rd')
client = APIClient()
client.force_authenticate(user=user)
r = client.post('/api/v1/event/', {'name': 'testevent'}, format='json')
```

Getting the following error:

```
  user = User.objects.create_user('username', 'Pas$w0rd')
  File "/opt/dev/wgptx/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 277, in __get__
    self.model._meta.swapped,
AttributeError: Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'account.User'
```

Any help please ?

Comment: What is the `User` reference in your test module?

Comment: from django.contrib.auth.models import User

Comment: Are you using the extended user model ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error seems like you are using the extended user model.
 So you should use
 **`from account.models import User`**

Hence your test module be like,

```
from account.models import User

user = User.objects.create_user('username', 'Pas$w0rd')
user = authenticate(username='username', password='Pas$w0rd')
client = APIClient()
client.force_authenticate(user=user)
r = client.post('/api/v1/event/', {'name': 'testevent'}, format='json')
```

**OR**
 Use the [**`get_user_model`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model) function as,

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

user = User.objects.create_user('username', 'Pas$w0rd')
user = authenticate(username='username', password='Pas$w0rd')
client = APIClient()
client.force_authenticate(user=user)
r = client.post('/api/v1/event/', {'name': 'testevent'}, format='json')
```